How to initialize multiple bootstrap tooltips with Blazor server components?
I'm trying to initialize multiple tooltips on a page, including tooltips in blazer components, but nothing works and there are no errors.
This is didn't work for me:
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs- 
toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})

And this too:
const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new 
bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))

But for a single tooltip this method works great:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-bs-toggle=tooltip]' }); 
});

Maybe someone has already encountered something similar. I tried to connect the script everywhere possible and tried different versions of bootstrap.

Here are the working steps for you:
1.Ensure you have jQuery and Bootstrap included in your _Host.cshtml for Blazor Server:
@page "/"

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    //...
</head>
<body>
     //...
    <!-- Bootstrap JS and dependencies -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/test.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

2.Create a JavaScript file named test.js in the wwwroot folder with the following content:
window.initializeTooltips = () => {
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })

};
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.initializeTooltips();
});    

3.Modify your Blazor component to call this JavaScript function.
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1 data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Hello, Tooltip!">Hover over me</h1>
<button data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip on button">Hover over button</button>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeTooltips");
        }
    }
}


Thank you! "Ensure you have jQuery and Bootstrap included in your _Host.cshtml for Blazor Server:" - this is not blazor pages. I use blazor components with MVC and Razor pages and i haven't _Host.cshtml. I thought that in this situation blazor should use dependencies from the shared layout.

Hi @UNRE, you never said this in your question. Pls share more details for the Program.cs and how do you integrate blazor components to ASP.NET Core MVC project.
